# Build fails when one library depends on another in angular6 workspace

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

Could someone help with an Angular 6 problem please?

I have a Angular 6 CLI project (application) and have added two libraries (lets call them `libA` and `libB` and `libA` requires components from `libB`)

I have imported `libB` into my `libA` module imports, but when building `libA` I get an error that it cannot find the module
`libB` module

My `libA` module is

```
import {LibBModule} from ‘@scope/libb’;
…
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LibBModule
  ]
})
export class LibAModule { }
```

In my root tsconfig paths i have

```
“@scope/lib1": [
  "dist/@scope/liba"
],
“@scope/libb": [
  "dist/@scope/libb"
]
```

I have built `libB` and that builds fine and is in the location above, but when i build `libA` i get the following error

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module ‘@scope/libb’
```

What have i done wrong? (NOTE: I am importing the `libA` module into my root project and that is fine), please help?

Comment: Do you use a tsconfig.app.json that also references paths?

Comment: I have `tsconfig.json` in the root folder and `tsconfig.lib.json` in each of the libraries. Have tried added the `paths` in there but still fails to build

Comment: I experienced problems when referencing a path configuration object in each, it seemed that the path itself was not actually extended, but overwritten by the extending tsconfig.*.json

Comment: I found this on GitHub https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10665

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm completely stuck and I've gone through every damn Github issue there is on this without any working solution...

Comment: Anyone find a solution? If so please share... My turn to be stuck :(

Comment: The only solution I know is using [NX](http://nx.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

it may be totally stating the obvious but I had this issue where one library relied on another and it was the *order of the build* which mattered.

So, in your case, i'd build Lib B first, *then* build Lib A.

Hope this works :)

p.s.just noticed how old this thread is, but hope the answer helps someone.